# datagrid checkbox writes Null instead of 0 (false) into database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Table in my sql-database that has the following fields: Name(string), Quartal1(bit), Quartal2(bit), Quartal3(bit), Quartal4(bit).

I bound that Table to a datagrid (winform in visual studio). I have a Checkbox for every Quartal and save the dataset into my database. It works actually it writes a 1 for checked into my database BUT it writes a NULL instead of a 0 (for false) into my database for unchecked. I tried to change the "FalseValue" & "TrueValue" property to "FALSE" and "TRUE" or "0" and "1" but it doesnt help. I also changed the field property "NULLS ALLOWED" to "NULLS NOT ALLOWED" but that didnt help as well. Since i need a 0 for not checked i need your help to accomplish that.

Comment: Change the databse table to stop NULLs too for starters

Comment: since i did everything with drag and drop i have no code. I changed the default value to "false" and when vstudio tries to write the value into the database it gives me the error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column q2, table XXX; column does not allow nulls. Insert fails." that means that visual studio doenst except the default value and sets an unchecked checkbox to NULL and tries to write that into the database where nulls are not allowed. how can i force visual studio to use its default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it didnt work. What helped was that i created a new dataset and used the designer-view. Here you can set a default value (default was something like ) to the one i needed (in this case 0). Now it writes the value into the database.