# DataGridVeiw update adapter sets 'Null' value in mysql database for Boolean data type if DataGridViewCheckBox Column is unchecked

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

My Code

```
    private MySqlDataAdapter daCust;
    private DataSet dsCustomer;             // Dataset
    private string CustTable = "Customer";  // Table Name


    MySqlCommandBuilder cmb1 = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daCustomer);                
    daCustomer.Update(dsCust, CustTable);
```

The customer has 2 columns -

```
Name (String)
Cancelled (Boolean)
```

it is showing as a checkbox on DataGridView.

On firing the update query, if cancelled is unchecked, the adapter set the Database(MySql) value as 'NULL' wherein, it should have set it as `'0'`

How can I make it set to `'0'` in the database?

Comment: It sounds to me like you've got the `ThreeState` property set to `true` when you want it `false`.

Comment: Did you check this [datagrid checkbox writes Null instead of 0 (false) into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041417/datagrid-checkbox-writes-null-instead-of-0-false-into-database)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - It was already false. But your answer lead me to the right property that i was over looking. For the checkbox in Datagridview, there are 3 properties - 
1) False Value ( I now, set it to '0' which actually did the work)
2) Indeterminate Value
3) True Value Value 

under 'DATA' head.

Many thanks!

Comment: @sohaiby - I found the solution without the need of creating the new dataset in designer view. Please read the previous comment and Thank you!